# What does the badge Quorum mean ?

Tags: discussion

I just received teh 'Quoraum' badge over on AE.

It says 'One questio with score 2 on meta ?'

I read it , but still don't understand it.

Or is it brand new ?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a badge that rewards Meta activity.

There's two versions: one for asking questions, the other for answering them and receiving upvotes for both efforts.